# Eclipse interruptions under Mac OS 10.7 Lion

Tags: java, eclipse, osx-lion, interruption

I upgraded to Mac OS 10.7 Lion a while ago, and although Eclipse (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Helios Service Release 2) works fine two things go very slow:

- Creating a new project used to take a few seconds, now it takes about 1.5 minutes.
- Every now and then when saving my classes everything stops, and the spinning wait cursor appears for about 1 minute. The Activity monitor labels Eclipse as "not responding" during that time.

I have the latest Eclipse update. Does anybody know what could cause this behavior?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: If I were you and I would download the latest eclipse and point my workspace to the old one and give it a shot before digging further into this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try cleaning Eclipse, run this from the command line, in the directory where Eclipse is installed:

```
./eclipse -clean -vmargs -XstartOnFirstThread
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried both ideas: Óscar López' helpful suggestion made things go a little faster, Bragboy's suggestion (which included installing Eclipse all new) cured the whole thing completely, so that everything works fine and fast as it used to be. (I still wonder why things slowed-down, as I installed the latest updates.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding more heap space. In your eclipse.ini file in the installation increase the max heap (-Xmx). It's likely you are near the limit of the memory, so it's excessively garbage collecting.